# Magento module system.xml checkbox won't save

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

In Magento v1.5.0.1, does anyone know of an issue using the `<frontend_type>checkbox</frontend_type>` configuration directive in the system.xml?  In even the simplest of dumb modules that only have a single config variable and no blocks/models, if I check the box and hit "Save" it reloads the page with the checkbox deselected, even though it says that the configuration was saved successfully.  I searched through the code and it's only used in a couple of places.  Most of the time, people use `<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>` with `<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>`.  This works, but why doesn't the checkbox work too?  Or am I misunderstanding how the Magento checkbox is *supposed* to work?

If it helps, here are my files.  In this case I've added a text field variable as well.  If I enter text and hit save, that does save, but the checkbox does not:

### **config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Brian_Stupid>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Brian_Stupid>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <stupid translate="title">
                                            <title>Stupid Crap</title>
                                        </stupid>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

### system.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <stupid translate="label">
            <label>Stupid Test</label>
            <tab>catalog</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>998</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <debug translate="label">
                    <label>Debugging</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <debugmode translate="label">
                            <label>Debug Mode Enable</label>
                            <comment>If enabled, does not alter database. Prints debug messages and dies</comment>
                            <frontend_type>checkbox</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </debugmode>
                        <texttest translate="label">
                            <label>Text Test</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </texttest>
                    </fields>
                </debug>
            </groups>
        </stupid>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Answer (score 6):

I post you my solution as I'm facing a similar situation

Basically the problem is that magento save only the input parameter 'value' in db while in the input checkbox the important value is 'Checked'.

I tried to put some js that when the checkbox change set the input value according to this and when the page load does the opposite ... This doesn't work.

alternative solution: use a dropdown

> ```
>  <debugmode translate="label">
>                         <label>Debug Mode Enable</label>
>                         <comment>If enabled, does not alter database. Prints debug messages and dies</comment>
>                         <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>                                                                     
>                         <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>     
>                         <sort_order>10</sort_order>
>                         <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
>                         <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
>                         <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
>                     </debugmode>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

i spend some time to get a solution, but there is none, except one.

Take a look at the PayPal module in Mage-Folder. Thats the Only module who uses Checkboxed, but they were set in a quite difficult way.

I guess thats the reason why everyone uses a select with yesno or enabledisable source.

Comment: I noticed that in the PayPal module also and couldn't figure it out.  I'll take another look at it sometime and see if I can make sense of it.  For now, the yes/no is working fine, but I hope someone reads this thread who knows more about checkboxes.  Anyone?